# Cannot set Expression. It is marked as 'NonShareable' and has already been used

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, itemssource

iv'e created a custom control deriving from ItemsControl .

```
public class CustsomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{ }
```

XAML  :

```
  <local:CustsomSelectorControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}"> 
        <local:CustsomSelectorControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>                  
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CustsomSelectorControl.ItemTemplate>
    </local:CustsomSelectorControl>
```

The Control Template :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustsomItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustsomItemsControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

in DataContext :

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add(new Person("A"));
        People.Add(new Person("B"));
        People.Add(new Person("C"));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("People"));
        }
    }
```

The items are never set , iv'e observed this with snoop ,the ItemsSource property 
is marked in **RED** but there are no BindingErrors , when i delve the BindingExpression 
i get an ArgumentExpression:

```
 Cannot set Expression. It is marked as 'NonShareable' and has already been used.
```

Comment: Why are you subclassing WPF UI elements to begin with? And where is the `DataContext` being set?

Comment: the DataContext is the windows code behind ,  
and for your vary important question of WHY i am subclassing WPF UI elements , it is because a Leprechaun told me to !

Comment: leprechauns don't have a reputation of being good WPF developers. You need a good reason to subclass WPF UI elements. You still don't tell me where is the `DataContext = this` line or something.

Comment: is it necessary ? 
do i need to declare that in the Main Window constructor ?

Comment: otherwise the `DataContext` for the whole thing is going to be `null` and no data will be shown. Would you please tell me `why` are you subclassing WPF UI elements?

Comment: o'k that was the problem , add an answer and i'll mark it 
thanks.

i usually work using MVVM so i didn't think of that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` properly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; //This is what you're missing
    ...
}
```

Still, you need to have a really strong reason to subclass `ItemsControl`.

Comment: it's a custom selector which exposes some extra features , such as 
DragDrop notations , and a metadata override with a callback for IsEnabled.
for now ...